# Where is the best place to handle tdl redirects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, http-redirect

So we have a domain... domainxyz.com

We also have a few other tdls..

- domainxyz.de
- domainxyz.co.uk

I need to redirect all of these domains to the .com. I could do this at the server, map all domains to the same server, and then on the server handle the redirects.

However, we are also using AWS Route53, is it a better idea to handle this sort of thing there?

Answer (score 0):

DNS as a protocol doesn't do redirects. What you're probably referring to is a CNAME record which is not a redirect. Instead it will point your DNS resolver to where the records for this domain are, the domain itself doesn't change.

Redirects as in HTTP Redirects could be handled at the server or Application Load Balancer (if you're using one).
See: [How can I redirect one domain to another domain using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-to-another-domain-with-alb/)